# Why EKS Fluent Bit error EC2 on Metabase?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-eks, fluent-bit

I'm trying to deploy the fluentbit in my EKS but I'm facing this error on the pods from fluentbit:

```
`[2023/09/27 19:59:54] [error] [filter:aws:aws.2] Could not retrieve ec2 metadata from IMDS`
```

Can anyone help me?

The nodes from my cluster have the Metabase enabled, but the error still continues.

Comment: Please accept the answer if your issue resolved.

Answer (score 0):

The AWS EC2 instances now support IMDSv2. It's crucial to ensure consistency in the IMDS version between EKS and the Fluent Bit config map.

**For Node in EC2:**
[image] [image]

In the images, you can observe that if IMDSv2 is required, you need to set IMDSv2 in Fluent Bit. If optional, then IMDSv1 will work.

**For EKS:**
You can check the IMDS version via the config map using the command: `kubectl edit cm fluent-bit-config -n amazon-cloudwatch`. Change the version, and then delete the existing pod using `kubectl delete pod fluent-bit-1234 -n amazon-cloudwatch`. This action triggers the automatic creation of the daemon set pod.

Reference Link:
1.https://github.com/fluent/fluent-bit/issues/2840#issuecomment-1117176115
2.[https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/instancedata-data-retrieval.html](https://github.com/fluent/fluent-bit/issues/2840#issuecomment-1117176115)    3.[https://aws.amazon.com/about-aws/whats-new/2020/08/amazon-eks-supports-ec2-instance-metadata-service-v2/](https://github.com/fluent/fluent-bit/issues/2840#issuecomment-1117176115)      4.[https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/configuring-IMDS-new-instances.html](https://github.com/fluent/fluent-bit/issues/2840#issuecomment-1117176115)